# Convert to a ternary expression

Tags: python

How would I convert the following to a ternary expression?

```
requester_annotation = hit_data.get('RequesterAnnotation')
if requester_annotation == 'None':
    requester_annotation = None
```

So far I have:

```
requester_annotation = hit_data.get('RequesterAnnotation') \
                       if hit_data.get('RequesterAnnotation') != 'None' \
                       else None
```

But this is even longer than what I have to begin with!

Comment: It seems unclear what you are looking for, as you already have it converted to a ternary expression. Are you looking for something more succinct or pythonic?

Comment: If hit_data.get is expensive, I don't think you want to because there's no way to avoid calling it twice

Comment: I suppose `hd=hit_data.get(...); request_annotation = hd if hd != 'None' else None` would work, but it's just sytactic sugar. Personally I think your original form more clearly expresses the intent

Comment: The only improvement you can make with your current code is to enclose it in parentheses to get rid of line continuations... However, there are probably more pythonic approaches to the whole thing. Can you tell us more about `hit_data`? Is it a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do. In python, ternary expressions, or conditional expressions are of the following format:

```
x if test else y
```

If this is the only check you plan on doing, then I would just leave it as you first wrote it. On the other hand, if you plan on having multiple conditional checks, then consider creating a new dict and removing the *'None's*. Something along the lines of:

```
dict((x,y) for x,y in hit_data.items() if y != 'None')
```

Of course, it implies the hit_data is not that large.